# Can translation invariance be achieved by just a global pooling layer?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I am trying to understand the purpose of the max pooling layers that are insterted between intermediate convolutional layers. As we know, the outputs of convolutional layers are translational equivariant. That is, if a filter has learn to detect a nose, if the nose is shifted the activation in the resulting feature map will also be shifted by the same amount.

So, we can scan the output of Conv(n) layer with the filters from the Conv(n+1) layer and still detect the relevant features. Then, we can use a global pooling operation after the final Conv layer to make our architecture translation invariant. What is the purpose of the Max Pooling layer then?

In the [Deep Learning Book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/), it is stated that:

> Invariance to local translation can be a very useful property if we care more about whether some feature is present than exactly where it is.

Can't we achieve this by just using a Global Pooling layer after the final Conv layer?

I add the following image from the [Hands-on Machine Learning with
Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/) from which I can see a potential disadvantage of not using Max Pooling layers:

[image]

Suppose that the black pixels (**lets say black pixel means 1 and white pixel means 0**) on the output of the Max Pooling correspond to some detected feature. Then, the output of next Conv layer, assuming a filter with values and a stride of 2:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Conv output (assuming left Max Pooling)**
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Conv output (assuming mid Max Pooling)**
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Conv output (assuming right Max Pooling)**
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4 \\
0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Intuitively, the problem I see is that by not being translation invariant the following layers after this Conv layer will receive different outputs and this will make their job harder during training since they have to readjust the values of their filter weights depending on where exactly the feature was detected. Is this intuition correct?

Answer (score 4):

> Intuitively, the problem I see is that by not being translation invariant the following layers after this Conv layer will receive different outputs and this will make their job harder during training since they have to readjust the values of their filter weights depending on where exactly the feature was detected. Is this intuition correct?

This intuition is correct. We need local translation invariance achieved by applying small pooling layers. Global pooling is an overkill for every pooling layer. It guarantees invariance but gets rid of many other useful interactions that could be learnt by the next convolutional layers.

Comment: Neverthless is not overkill after the final convolutional layer right?

Comment: Well, as you said, it's the final layer, and we expect the network to summarize the information up until that point. But, if you do that in the first conv. layer, how is that going to be possible?

Comment: Of course, that's why I said in the OP that the Global Pooling should be after the final Conv layer.

Comment: Maybe I need to ask clarifications for this: In response to "Invariance to local translation can be a very useful property if we care more about whether some feature is present than exactly where it is.", you ask "Can't we achieve this by just using a Global Pooling layer after the final Conv layer?" So, what I understand from these two sentences is we drop the intermediate max pooling layers, and just use a global pool layer after the final convolution, and we still get the translation invariance. Isn't this what you mean?

Comment: Apologize if I was misunderstood. Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Having only final pooling layer means, you do conv after conv, which effectively is a single conv.

Comment: With non-linearities though between the conv layers.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't catch that. Then, assuming all convs and activations in-between, what this design suggests is you rectify your intermediate outputs with the approximate locations of the signals every time. It's like a self-correcting algorithm in case of small perturbations. Move an object one pixel left/right, the output will be the same/very similar. What you're suggesting is, doing it only in the final layer, with the accummulated perturbation debt up until that point. And, that's not equivalent to "local" translation invariance. That is just some sort of invariance, but not we ask for.

Comment: "that's not equivalent to "local" translation invariance. That is just some sort of invariance, but not we ask for". Can you elaborate please on this because this might be where I get it wrong. When we classify images, we don't care whether a face cat was found on top left or bottom right or in the middle of the image. So if we assume that the final conv layer summarizes such high level features, then we can use global pooling. I think I don't understand why max pooling is usefull at all.

Comment: If there is no local invariance, it'll be harder to learn the coefficients because then the cat face could have been in any location in the image. The pooling operation reduces the search space, and small translations does not require special attention.

Comment: If I get it right, in order to recognize a cat face we need somehow to detect two eyes, a nose and a mouth. If we don't use max pooling, since the absolute positions of these 4 may vary from image to image, it will be difficult for conv layers to adjust the weights. In contrast, when max pooling is used we pretty much discard the absolute positions and we care only about the relative ones, which make now the training easier for conv layers?

Comment: Using your simplified analogy (because it depends on the network of how face detection occurs), the absolute positions have some freedom to change a few pixels, thanks to pooling. The role of relative positions is a bit different. This information is generally used in the subsequent layers while combining information from different convolutional filters and making a decision. But, this certainly makes the decision layers easier as you also pointed out.